# Formulae to find sum of all digits before n?

Tags: algorithms, project-euler

I've just started to learn algorithm by joining Project Euler, and trying to understand the below formula

```
//3+6+9+12+......+999 = 3*(1+2+3+4+...+333)
//5+10+15+...+995 = 5*(1+2+....+199)

// 1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1) / 2

//solution: (p * (n * (n + 1))) / 2
```

I simply couldn't form the linkage, how do OP actually form the formula of `n * (n+1) / 2`? Can anyone please break it down further? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sum them in pairs: The first and last number, the second and the second to last, and so on. You see that you always get the same sum $1+n=n+1$, $2+(n-1)=n+1$, $3+(n-2)=n+1$... So, the total is $n+1$ times the number of pairs.

Comment: @user647486: Ahh now I see it! Wow this is mind blowing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Isaac You can also prove the formula by induction, but the pairing method is of course much more elegant and easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer consists of two sections.

---

**Section 1:** The General Summation Formula.

Consider finite (sorted) sequences $S$ of the form

$\quad k,\, k + g,\, k+2g,\, k+3g,\, \dots,\, k+(n-1)g$

where $k$, $g$, and $n$ are positive integers.

We are seeking a summation formula for the terms in $S$.

The integer $n$ is the length of the list $S$ of numbers.

If $n$ is even we can employ an summation algorithm that keeps on 'pairing off' the largest with smallest numbers. There are $\frac{n}{2}$ pairs of numbers and so the sum of all the numbers in $S$ is given by

$$\tag 1 \frac{n}{2}\,[k + (k + (n-1)g)]$$

If $n$ is odd then there are $\frac{n-1}{2}$ pairs of numbers and the middle term has value

$\quad k + \frac{n-1}{2}g = \frac{[k + (k + (n-1)g)]}{2}$

So the summation of all the terms in the odd case is given by

$\quad \frac{n-1}{2}\,[k + (k + (n-1)g)] + \frac{[k + (k + (n-1)g)]}{2}$

Fortunately, this formula is algebraically the same as the formula derived when there are an even number of terms.

So the summation of all the terms in $S$ is given by $\text{(1)}$.

Note that when $k = g$ the summation is given by

$$ g \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

---

**Section 2:** Deriving the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ Summation Formula Using [Sigma Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Recall

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n n = n^2 $$
Let

$\quad x = \sum_{i=1}^n i$

Then

$\quad 2x = \sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^n i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i + 1) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n - i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n + 1) =$

$\quad \quad (n + 1)^2 - (n+1) = n(n+1)$

So

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$